# Excel VBA web scraping from table

Tags: html, css, vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to extract some info from the table below into Excel using VBL without any success. The values which I need do not seem to have any element ID, tag name or class name assigned to it.  I'm after the Fuel Usage value(89218) and the time value in the same row (01:15). Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to scrape values from a table, or how to extract data from specific TR, TD.

HTML source of the table:

```
<h3>Airbus A300-600-PW4158 Fuel Planner</h3>
<p>London to Chicago  EGKK-KORD (3441 NM)<br /></p>
<h2>Total Fuel: 101901 POUNDS</h2>
<table width="100%" border=1>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;</th>
        <th style="text-align:left;">Fuel</td>
        <th style="text-align:left;">Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fuel Usage</td>
        <td>89218</td>
        <td>08:47</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Reserve Fuel</td>
        <td>12682</td>
        <td>01:15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fuel on Board</td>
        <td>101901</td>
        <td>10:02</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

much appreciated.

Comment: Which values do you need?

Comment: I need the 98218 value, and the 08:47 value.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS Selectors:**

Without seeing more of the HTML you can use the following CSS selectors selectors for the snippet shown:

```
tr td:nth-child(2)
tr td:nth-child(3)
```

With CSS selectors this will bring back nodeLists of all 2 or 3 child `td`s with a `tr`.

For example:

[image: CSS Selectors]

You can access individual items from a nodeList by index.

---

VBA:

The syntax in vba overall will be something like:

```
.document.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-child(2)")(0).innerText
```

or possibly

```
.document.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-child(2)").Item(0).innerText
```

The `0` is hypothetical. You would need to inspect your  full HTML to ascertain the correct index to use.

The `.document` innerHTML can  be populated from the `.responseText` using IE, for example, to navigate to the page.

Comment: This assuming VBA supports the above selectors of nth-child